# batch file to copy files to newly created folder with date name

Tags: batch-file, automation, copy

I'm making a system that our employees need to store files to that are ment to be processed. This process however deletes the source files and I want to make a backup prior to these files being processed.
The files need to be stored in an automatically created folder with name being today's date. The files vary in filetype.

The first part, creating a folder with today's date, I managed to figure out. The second part, copying files from a general folder to this newly created folder is something I can't get to work.

This is the code I have so far

```
@echo off
set date="%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%"
set "source=C:\b2g\2021\general"
set "destination=C:\b2g\2021\%date%"
mkdir "C:\b2g\2021\%date%"
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /mir /minage:%X%

exit /b
```

This is creating the folder, but is not copying any files to that folder.

any help is very kindly apreciated

Comment: You have not figured out the first part at all. First of all you appear to be overwriting the important environment variable `%DATE%`, which is certainly not a wise idea. Next the output of `%DATE%`, is locale, PC, and user configurable, and because your code assumes the positions of characters within its output, you cannot expect them to meet with your intentions. There are many questions and answers on this site which show you how to retrieve the date in a consistent format on any PC, from a batch file. Please use the search facility to locate, and adapt them as needed. BTW, what is `%X%`?

Comment: If you don't have the expertise to find them on this site using the appropriate tags, and search strings, you'll certainly not find them anywhere else, without just getting lucky. Please take a look at [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to assist you in how to narrow down your searching on this site, _(which should certainly include the tag [[tag:batch-file]] and the string `date`)_. The site guidelines are that we do not answer duplicated questions. Also as you're only using a few commands, their usage information is available at the Command Prompt, `yourcommand /?`.

Comment: I've searched for and found the topics that cover this issue on various sites, that's how I got that first part of code. I just lack the expertise to translate the answers given there into a piece of code that I'm looking for, and I'm humbly asking the many experts to assist me with that last piece of work. Sharing knowledge is not just telling ppl they need to search better.
Like I said that code I posted will create a folder with the current date. The only thing that's not working is the part where the files get copied to that newly created folder.